# Cannot remove file from working directory

Tags: git

I'm trying to checkout a branch, but keep getting this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        file.txt
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

However:

- When I `stash`, nothing changes. file.txt is still in the working
  directory.
- When I `add` the file and then `stash`, it goes back to the
  working directory.
- When I `reset --hard`, nothing changes. file.txt is
  still in the working directory.
- When I `checkout --` the current
  branch, nothing changes. file.txt is still in the working directory.
- I even tried `git rm -f file.txt` and then `stash`. Doesn't help either.

And after doing all this, I'm still unable to checkout a different branch because I'm stuck with file.txt.

How can I explain what's happening here? And how do I get rid of file.txt?

I'm working with git-scm on Windows, if it matters.

**EDIT:** `git diff --check` shows that there's a difference in trailing whitespace. Why can't git just treat trailing whitespace just like any other text difference, and instead acts so strangely by not letting me `reset` or `stash`? Is this behavior configurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up removing the `text=auto` setting, because we all work on Windows anyway. Now Windows line-endings are kept in the repository and it seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the repository contains both `File.txt` and `file.txt` (which might have happened if you are collaborating with people that use Linux or Mac). Windows thinks this is the same file, so only one of them will exist in the working directory, and git will always think that the other one is changed.

To check whether this actually is the problem, run this command:

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD
```

and look for files with different casing in the same directory (or directories with different casing).

The easiest way to fix this will be to get someone on another platform to remove or rename either file.

(If your project somehow depends on having both files, the solution is to either rethink that requirement or to switch away from Windows...)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this is not the case (no pun intended :) )

Comment: :D - Are there any non-English characters in the file's name or path?

Comment: No, all characters belong to `[a-zA-Z.]`

Comment: What happens if you delete the file with `del` or Explorer? (After copying it if you care about its contents...)

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing and was finally able to do a checkout. But I'm not happy with this solution, as this problem keeps reappearing...

Comment: It really looks like something is wrong with the internal repository structure. What does `git fsck` tell you?

Answer (score 1):

You might have an issue with line endings read the following:

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Long story short, try change `.gitattributes` file as following:

```
* text=auto => #* text=auto
```

Or

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Another option is to commit the file

It all depends if all of the developers work on the same platform or not..